# Is Mason a framework?

Tags: perl, web-applications, frameworks, mason

I've been having an agruement with a friend that Mason (Perl) is not a framework, but a templating language. I feel Mason for Perl does what JSP does for Java (as an analogy, not pure technical comparison). From what I know, JSP is not a framework and I feel neither is Mason. When I looked up wikipedia [Mason (Perl)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_%28Perl%29), I see that the main site says it is a web application framework written in Perl while the discussion page contests it.

Any pointers on why it is/ it is not a framework?

Update based on comments from ysth:
For a framework, I feel it should at least make db access easy, manage sessions, basic security that a webapp would need, templating and code reuse (or libraries that make basic tasks easy).

Comment: You probably want to qualify your question as "is it a web application framework", since unqualified "framework" can apply to almost anything.

Comment: Perhaps you could post an answer to your own question listing the attributes a web application framework must have and which ones Mason does or does not have?

Comment: I just got around to clean up the question again. Some of the answers indicate it too. The question was very open to interpretation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mason is an 'M' short of being a MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework.  It provides extensive rendering (View) features, which is why people think of Mason as being a templating language.  However it also provides quite a few dispatch mechanisms (epsecially in the form of dhandlers), and control mechanisms (which fit naturally into autohandlers).

A few years ago I wrote an [on-line tutorial](http://perltraining.com.au/talks/whirlwind/) (in Mason) to show off some of these features.  It's optimised for full-screen display, and needs javascript enabled.

What Mason doesn't give you is a database abstraction layer, so you have to bring your own Model.

To the best of my knowledge amazon.com is written in Mason, along with [many other sites](http://masonhq.com/?MasonPoweredSites).

If you enjoy working with Mason, but you'd like to have a Model, more toys, and a pony, then you may consider looking at [Jifty](http://jifty.org/) as a web application framework.

Comment: Hey, your link doesn't work.  I would love to see your tutorial.

Comment: ^ second that, 7 years later! o_o!

Answer (score 4):

A templating system would be something like `HTML::Template`, that is, a module that only does templating.

I feel that `Mason` does more, it has somehow a routing mechanism, it provides argument handling though `%ARGS`, intialisations through `%INIT`.

It also provides interfaces to `mod_perl`, `CGI`...

Now, it does not talk to the database, as if you want a clean way to do it, you'll have to use `Class::DBI`, `DBIx::Perlish` or one of the other hundred perl modules that does object mapping, or whatever else...

Answer (score 4):

Can't answer the question to whether HTML::Mason is or isn't a framework without looking at it but I'm always happy with the following definition....

> "a framework calls your program whereas your program calls a library"

Answer (score 4):

It is not an [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) type of framework, it is probably closer to PHP than Ruby on Rails for example (and just as bad from what I have seen of it).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Embedded Perl in HTML with Mason](http://www.masonbook.com/book/chapter-1.mhtml#TOC-ANCHOR-7) view of its competition, I'd say it is a template language.  Otherwise [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) and [Maypole](http://maypole.perl.org/) would be on the list.  Also, I think I read somewhere that you can use Mason as the [View](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-View-Mason/lib/Catalyst/View/Mason.pm) portion in a Catalyst application.

I guess I can see where you can use it like a framework, but it seems to be more complete if you view it as a template language.

Answer (score 1):

Mason alone is not a framework it's just a template system BUT with some very cool features. It's got it's own structure and you can embed perl code very easely in it also it's got cache support. I've seen people who use Mason alone for developing a large application, but I guess it works better in an MVC framework.

Take care!

Answer (score 1):

HTML::Mason is what frameworks want to become when they get older. With HTML::Mason you get:

- a dispatcher
- templating
- caching
- logging
- extremely flexible modularization

It was designed for high performance multi-tiered web applications, not for pleasing the fans of design patterns borrowed from desktop programming (such as MVC was).

Answer (score 1):

The following definition of a framework is taken from the Gamma book on Design Patterns. "A framework is a set of cooperating classes that make up a reusable design for a specific class of software." Mason, by that definition, is a framework.  An MVC framework is only one type of framework.

Answer (score 0):

Depends of your definition of framework.

You can apply name framework to any library if it does more than one thing.